# How to install NLTK 3.0 on Python 3.3 on 32 bit windows. Tried all ways but still unsuccessful

Tags: nltk

I tried install it using nltk-3.2.1 source and installer files I downloaded from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nltk

I also tried installing it using pip 
pip install nltk.

It would be great if someone could explain the entire process in detail

Comment: Explain what you did and what messages you received and maybe someone can help

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/alvations/0ed8641d7d2e1941b9f9

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

- Download 32bit python executable from
  https://www.python.org/downloads/
- Install it and add path of the Python27 directory to the path variable under windows settings
- to install NLTK in windows we required Numpy as pre-requisites (Although it is optional). But I recommended to install it.
- To install numpy we required pip and easy_install package must be available under Scripts folder of Python27 directory. To do that go the following link https://bootstrap.pypa.io/.
- Download and execute the get-pip.py file. After doing that add the Scripts directory to the windows path. Now you are ready to install NLTK to your Windows PC.
- Open Command prompt as Administrator (start->run->cmd)
- Type pip install nltk (it will take sometimes and finally it will show successfully installed)
- To check NLTK is installed or not open the python compiler by typing python in windows shell
- type import nltk to the python shell. If no error means it is installed successfully.
- Next step to download the nltk data and corpus. To do that type "nltk.download()" to python prompt.

Enjoy!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
for any other quires regarding the installation mail me goutam.nita@gmail.com